# How to get a parameter I am fetching with one Graph QL query into the second Graph QL query

Tags: reactjs, api, graphql

I have two queries for the same Graph QL API endpoint. The second query needs to have a parameter I am fetching in the first query. (image id) How would I get the id from query one into query two? I don't know if it is possible but both information must be then displayed at the same time and update at the same time.

Query 1

```
users {
      name {
        adress {
          image id
       {
            image name
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Query 2

```
user {
        adress {
          image id (image id: $image id)
       {
            image name
          }
        }
    }
```

How would I get the id from query one into query two? I don't know if it is possible but both information must be then displayed at the same time and update at the same time.